# Weka and SQL Server 2019 (Mac OS Big Sur 11.5 beta, MacBook Pro M1) connection problems

Tags: java, sql-server, connection, weka, monetdb

Good evening. I hope someone can help me with this one...

1. I made sure I installed weka 2-8-5 azul zulu for mac, Intel, since the ARM dmg installer seems to be corrupted. I get a damaged package message, using OS big sur 11.5 beta and MacBookPro M1.
2. I'm using openjdk 11 (AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9))
3. I installed the dmg and copied app and weka folder to my /Applications folder
4. I added my preferred JDBC drivers both to /Libraries/Java/Extensions (SQL Server, MySQL and MonetDB).
5. Also added JDBC drivers to my /Users/Myname/jdbc folder. (I read this in some forums).
6. Modified the /Users/Myname/wekafiles/props/DatabaseUtils.props to be like this...(trying to connect to MS SQL Server Edge 19 running on linux docker container. I can connect to SQL Server from Python, DBeaver and Azure Data Studio for Mac):

   ## Database settings for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition

   ## General information on database access can be found here:

   ## https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/databases/

   ## url:     http://www.microsoft.com/

   ## jdbc:    http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx

   ## author:  Fracpete (fracpete at waikato dot ac dot nz)

   ## version: $Revision: 15255 $

   ## JDBC driver (comma-separated list)

   jdbcDriver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

   ## database URL

   jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1443;databaseName=MyDB;

   ## specific data types

   ## string, getString() = 0;    --> nominal

   ## boolean, getBoolean() = 1;  --> nominal

   ## double, getDouble() = 2;    --> numeric

   ## byte, getByte() = 3;        --> numeric

   ## short, getByte()= 4;        --> numeric

   ## int, getInteger() = 5;      --> numeric

   ## long, getLong() = 6;        --> numeric

   ## float, getFloat() = 7;      --> numeric

   ## date, getDate() = 8;        --> date

   ## text, getString() = 9;      --> string

   ## time, getTime() = 10;       --> date

   ## timestamp, getTime() = 11;  --> date

   varchar=0
   float=2
   tinyint=3
   int=5

   ## values added manually

   string=0
   bigint=6
   nvarchar=9
   decimal=2
   bit=1

   ## other options

   CREATE_DOUBLE=DOUBLE PRECISION
   CREATE_STRING=VARCHAR(8000)
   CREATE_INT=INT
   CREATE_DATE=DATETIME
   DateFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
   checkUpperCaseNames=false
   checkLowerCaseNames=false
   checkForTable=true

   ## All the reserved keywords for this database

   ## Based on the keywords listed at the following URL (2009-04-13):

   ## http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822(SQL.90).aspx

   Keywords=
   ADD,
   ALL,
   ALTER,
   AND,
   ANY,
   AS,
   ASC,
   AUTHORIZATION,
   BACKUP,
   BEGIN,
   BETWEEN,
   BREAK,
   BROWSE,
   BULK,
   BY,
   CASCADE,
   CASE,
   CHECK,
   CHECKPOINT,
   CLOSE,
   CLUSTERED,
   COALESCE,
   COLLATE,
   COLUMN,
   COMMIT,
   COMPUTE,
   CONSTRAINT,
   CONTAINS,
   CONTAINSTABLE,
   CONTINUE,
   CONVERT,
   CREATE,
   CROSS,
   CURRENT,
   CURRENT_DATE,
   CURRENT_TIME,
   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   CURRENT_USER,
   CURSOR,
   DATABASE,
   DBCC,
   DEALLOCATE,
   DECLARE,
   DEFAULT,
   DELETE,
   DENY,
   DESC,
   DISK,
   DISTINCT,
   DISTRIBUTED,
   DOUBLE,
   DROP,
   DUMP,
   ELSE,
   END,
   ERRLVL,
   ESCAPE,
   EXCEPT,
   EXEC,
   EXECUTE,
   EXISTS,
   EXIT,
   EXTERNAL,
   FETCH,
   FILE,
   FILLFACTOR,
   FOR,
   FOREIGN,
   FREETEXT,
   FREETEXTTABLE,
   FROM,
   FULL,
   FUNCTION,
   GOTO,
   GRANT,
   GROUP,
   HAVING,
   HOLDLOCK,
   IDENTITY,
   IDENTITYCOL,
   IDENTITY_INSERT,
   IF,
   IN,
   INDEX,
   INNER,
   INSERT,
   INTERSECT,
   INTO,
   IS,
   JOIN,
   KEY,
   KILL,
   LEFT,
   LIKE,
   LINENO,
   LOAD,
   NATIONAL,
   NOCHECK,
   NONCLUSTERED,
   NOT,
   NULL,
   NULLIF,
   OF,
   OFF,
   OFFSETS,
   ON,
   OPEN,
   OPENDATASOURCE,
   OPENQUERY,
   OPENROWSET,
   OPENXML,
   OPTION,
   OR,
   ORDER,
   OUTER,
   OVER,
   PERCENT,
   PIVOT,
   PLAN,
   PRECISION,
   PRIMARY,
   PRINT,
   PROC,
   PROCEDURE,
   PUBLIC,
   RAISERROR,
   READ,
   READTEXT,
   RECONFIGURE,
   REFERENCES,
   REPLICATION,
   RESTORE,
   RESTRICT,
   RETURN,
   REVERT,
   REVOKE,
   RIGHT,
   ROLLBACK,
   ROWCOUNT,
   ROWGUIDCOL,
   RULE,
   SAVE,
   SCHEMA,
   SECURITYAUDIT,
   SELECT,
   SESSION_USER,
   SET,
   SETUSER,
   SHUTDOWN,
   SOME,
   STATISTICS,
   SYSTEM_USER,
   TABLE,
   TABLESAMPLE,
   TEXTSIZE,
   THEN,
   TO,
   TOP,
   TRAN,
   TRANSACTION,
   TRIGGER,
   TRUNCATE,
   TSEQUAL,
   UNION,
   UNIQUE,
   UNPIVOT,
   UPDATE,
   UPDATETEXT,
   USE,
   USER,
   VALUES,
   VARYING,
   VIEW,
   WAITFOR,
   WHEN,
   WHERE,
   WHILE,
   WITH,
   WRITETEXT

   ## The character to append to attribute names to avoid exceptions due to

   ## clashes between keywords and attribute names

   KeywordsMaskChar=_

   #flags for loading and saving instances using DatabaseLoader/Saver
   nominalToStringLimit=50
   idColumn=auto_generated_id
7. I copied the same props file (/users/Myname/wekafiles/DatabaseUtils.props)to the uncompressed weka.jar file in weka-3-8-5-azul-zulu.app java folder. (jar xf weka.jar)
8. Re packed the files and folders again to weka.jar (jar cf weka.jar *)
9. I checked that CLASSPATH env variable is well defined and sourced from .zprofile after rebooting the machine. JAVA_HOME also is well defined and working well.
10. nothing works... still get the message:

connecting to: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1443;databasename=MyDB = false

Unable to find a suitable driver...

Is there a better way to do this? I like Weka very much but I would like to train models with larger datasets in MySQL, SQLServer and MonetDB databases.

Any help highly appreciated.

Michael P.

Comment: _jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1443;databaseName=MyDB;_ fyi, the default SQL Server port is 1433. That won't stop you locating the driver, but it may stop you connecting.

Comment: My bad, that was a typo, I'm using tcp port 1433 indeed... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Mac user nor do I use Weka as a standalone tool much these days. But here is what worked for me on my Linux box just now, using Java 11.

Assuming that your `weka.jar` is located in the following directory (e.g., extracted from the platform-independent zip file):

```
~/tools/weka/weka-3-9-5
```

And all your JDBC driver jars are stored in this directory:

```
~/tools/jdbc
```

Then you can start Weka like this from the terminal, using a `CLASSPATH` variable just for this `java` invocation of the GUIChooser:

```
CLASSPATH=~/tools/weka/weka-3-9-5/weka.jar:~/tools/jdbc/* java weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

**NB:** This assumes that the `java` executable is available from a directory on your `PATH` environment variable.

The updated `DatabaseUtils.props` should go in `$HOME/wekafiles/props`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it didn't work. this helped though... https://www.reddit.com/r/datamining/comments/82sjlz/connecting_mysql_db_with_weka_on_mac/ 
Bottom line, you need to copy your JDBC jar files to  /Applications/weka-<version>/Contents/Java folder... I appreciate your help.